# Does HttpGetBinary waits until the whole file is downloaded?

Tags: function, http-get, lazarus, download

I am writing a mini utility program that will be used to download image files off the Internet directly. I would like to know if my program will wait at the function `HttpGetBinary` until the whole file finished downloading or my program will keep running past this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpGetBinary` is synchronous. It does not return until the file is completely downloaded.